# ASP Classic VB error 800a01a8 object required

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am attempting to fix an issue on a company website. The page in question is http://www.srbc.com/SiteMap.asp. I am getting the following error when trying to call a global options file:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>   Object required: ''
>   /_Includes/Callout_Global.asp, line 40

And this is the line the error references in the /_Includes/Callout_Global.asp file:

```
rs_main.open "Select TeamID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName from team where Category = 'Attorney' and IsActive = '1' Order by OrderNum"
```

The code controls the dropdown box that should contain a listing of attorney names.

This code works just fine on other pages in the site (see for example http://www.srbc.com/Careers/Default.asp).

I am not a coder, just trying to cleanup this site a bit. It is pretty dated code, but any suggestions on what I could do to fix this would be appreciated.

The coding on the SiteMap.asp page around where this function is called looks like:

```
<td width="210" valign="top" class="hideforprint">
<!--#include virtual="/_Includes/Callout_Global.asp" -->
</td>
<td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="726" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td height="25"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="22" valign="top" background="/Images/CommonImages/rightborder.gif">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--#include virtual="/_Includes/Footer.asp" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You tagged this as ASP.NET and VB.NET, but those technologies are unrelated to vbscript and classic ASP. Please remove those tags.

Answer (score 4):

That error would suggest that you haven't created an object called `rs_main`.  It looks like it should be a recordset object, so you earlier in your code you should have the line

```
Set rs_main = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Could you post the first 40 lines of Callout_Global.asp, there might be other stuff missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a dope!

I figured it out. At the top of the SiteMap.asp code, there was a function call missing. Once I added that back in, everything started working. I just noticed that was different from every other page that was working normally.

Now to tackle a search index issue.

Thanks!